# DBISAM database utility

Tags: dbisam

I have a DBISAM database that I need to open and view and eventually migrate to SQL server, if not atleast a comma separated file. Does anyone know of a util to do that?

Comment: just want to bump thsi question up

Answer (score 2):

DBISAM ships with a free DBSYS utility that lets you view tables, write queries and export results.

Answer (score 0):

The DBISAM guys sell an ODBC driver... Get it, and then you can really get to your data...
(I have used it a lot, and it works fine.)